# CKEditor openDialog placeholders

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a function which opens the placeholder dialog when a certain key is pressed. But when I select a placeholder and click "Ok", the placeholder value doesn't get inserted in the editor. But when I open the placeholder dialog via the toolbar button, the placeholder does get inserted in the editor.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I added in the `plugin.js`:

```js
editor.on('key', function(e) {
  if (e.data.domEvent.$.key == "[") {
    editor.openDialog('placeholder');
  };
});
```

I changed some things in the `placeholder.js`:
The available placeholders are inside an dropdown.
The placeholder data has been passed through by the init.

As you can see, I placed a `console.log(this.getValue());` inside the `commit: function( widget ){`.
The `console.log` is visible in the firebug console when I open the dialog via the placeholder button in the toolbar, but when I open the dialog by keypress it is not visible.

```js
'use strict';

CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'placeholder', function( editor ) {
  var lang = editor.lang.placeholder,
      generalLabel = editor.lang.common.generalTab,
      validNameRegex = /^[^\[\]<>]+$/;
  return {
    title: lang.title,
    minWidth: 300,
    minHeight: 80,
    contents: [
      {
        id: 'info',
        label: generalLabel,
        title: generalLabel,
        elements: [
          // Dialog window UI elements.
          {
            id: 'name',
            type: 'select',
            items: editor.config.placeholders,
            style: 'width: 100%;',
            label: lang.name,
            'default': '',
            required: true,
            validate: CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.regex( validNameRegex, lang.invalidName ),
            setup: function( widget ) {
              this.setValue( widget.data.name );
            },
            commit: function( widget ) {
              console.log(this.getValue());
              widget.setData( 'name', this.getValue() );
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the following code inside my placeholder/plugin.js:

```js
editor.on('key', function(e) {
  console.log(e.data.domEvent.$);
  if (e.data.domEvent.$.key == "[") {
    editor.openDialog('placeholder');
  };
});
```

I used the setKeystroke function when initiating the editor:

```js
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor',{
  placeholders: ["test1", "test2"],
  extraPlugins: 'placeholder'
});
editor.setKeystroke( 219, 'placeholder');
```

And this works!